# QByteArray remove first 4 lines

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray

I have QByteArray and need to remove first 4 lines. I can do it with regular expressions, for example, but is it some easier way?

UPD: first lines(more than 4) in my QByteArray is text, with '\n' in the end.

Comment: First 4 lines of what? What a sign of the end of the line?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov first lines are text, last signs are "\n"

Comment: Ok, Robert Franke provided possible answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about searching the fourth occurrence of '\n' (using int QByteArray::indexOf ( char ch, int from = 0 ) const) and then removing the bytes up to that position (using QByteArray & QByteArray::remove ( int pos, int len ))?

Edit: Not tested, but something along these lines:

```
QByteArray ba("first\nsecond\nthird\nfourth\nfifth");
size_t index = 0;
unsigned occur = 0;
while ((index = ba.indexOf('\n', index)) >= 0){ 
    ++occur;
    if (occur == 4){
        break;
    }   
}
if (occur == 4){
    ba.remove(0, index + 1); 
}
```

Comment: almost the same as with regex, but seems there is no more simple way =)